# File Not Found Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/5974291181_log.txt'

Tags: python

Здравствуйте столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я сделал телеграмм  бота который отвечает на комментарии
с начало всё правильно, нажимаю на старт и он мне пишет "Я на связи. Напиши мне Привет )" пишу привет
и появляется такая ошибка:

```
result = handler['function'](message)
  File "c:\data\data.py", line 49, in handle_text
    f=open('data/' + str(message.chat.id) + '_log.txt', 'a', encoding='UTF-8')
File Not Found Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/5974291181_log.txt''
```

`Я много что перепробовал: с файлом возился и ролики на ютубе смотрел что-то пытался сам сделать  но нечего получается всё также не видит директорию и выводит мне эту ошибку.Скажите пожалуйста что я сделал не так и мою ошибку.`

Comment: File "c:\data\data.py"  ошибка тут  ,  поставьте двойной слеш

Comment: Это вам не линукс, всё такое :)

Comment: @Vasilijs Так это сам питон пишет путь к скрипту, в котором ошибка, это нормальный путь

Comment: Попробуйте прописать полный путь для открываемого файла. Каталог, в котором лежит скрипт, и текущий каталог, с которым этот скрипт исполняется, могут различаться.

Comment: А как это сделать?

Comment: Ну, напишите вместо `f=open('data/' + ...` -> `f=open('c:/data/' + ...`

Answer (score 1):

если у вас папка `data` находиться в той же папке что и пайтон файл

```
import os
f=open(os.getcwd() +'\\data\\' + str(message.chat.id) + '_log.txt', 'a', encoding='UTF-8')
```

если же нет то указывайте точный путь к папке `data`

Answer (score -1):

Зачем логировать такого бота? Это нелогично, ведь это просто трата памяти.

Если это необходимо, то попробуй записать название файла в отдельной переменной, а не формируй его внутри`open()`

Чтобы проверить и исправить код с технической части, то используй библеотеку `os`, где есть прекрасная функция `exits("filename")` , которая проверяет файл на существование.

Надеюсь, что удастся исправить проблему. Удачи

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В данном случае понятно же, что человек учится. Он научится логированию на простом боте, пусть тут логирование и не нужно, и это хорошо. Потом когда когда логирование реально понадобится он будет уже уметь его делать.